# Delay receiving a message on an Azure ServiceBus Topic

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have a Topic created on an Azure Service Bus, and I can place messages onto it, and retrieve them off, all fine.

But I want to be able to have a message placed on the queue, but somehow set the filter on the subscription to ignore the message until a time set on/within the message.  For example: "Here's a item of work, but I don't want you to execute it until 17:00 this evening."

I have tried adding a SqlFilter, but have become lost with it.  I've found examples online of the highMessages and lowMessages, based on numbers, but I can't get it to work with a SubscriptionClient.

Is this possible, or do I simply have to delay *adding* the message to the queue until I'm ready to process it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters are for filtering based on the metadata about the message (headers) and not tied into a clock. Sounds like you want to defer a message. You can send your messages and set `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` property to whatever the time you'd like the message to be processed. Note that (quoting from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.scheduledenqueuetimeutc.aspx#Anchor_2)):

> Message enqueuing time does not mean that the message will be sent at the same time. It will get enqueued, but the actual sending time depends on the queue's workload and its state.